# css border artifacts from inline svgs

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am working with a react app in chrome that involves a lot of inline svgs.

The text will have black borders randomly around it if its near an inline svg. It will sometimes disappear or appear as I highlight text.

The only thing that's consistent is there is an inline svg on every page where the border appears.

[image: The black borders around the text between the images]

Adding

```
{ 
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

On a element with the border fixes it, but its not feasible to add it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` - that also seems to help in this kind of situation, along with `backface-visibility: hidden;`.

Comment: Would this wrap up all inline svg elements? Or the elements receiving the artifacts? The two are not always the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a background image on body using a &:before tag with a z-index.

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(14, 19, 28, 1) !important;
    background-image: 'background image url';
    background-blend-mode: lighten;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;

    &:before {
      z-index: -10;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: .5;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(14,19,28) 0%, rgb(0,0,0) 60%, rgb(80, 130, 160) 100%);
    }
  }
```

This was fixed by adding to the &:before

```
body {
   &:before {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
   }
}
```

as coffeebot suggested.